# Complex Integral With Complex Roots

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Trying to solve this complex integral, wondering if someone can help me with the next step. I'm using the formula:

$$\int_{\mu}\frac{1}{iz}F\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right),\frac{1}{2i}\left(z-\frac{1}{z}\right)\right) dz = \int_0^{2\pi}F(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta)) d\theta$$

The integral is:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{(a+\cos(\theta)(b+\sin(\theta))},\>\>\>\>a,b>1$$

I have simplified the integral to:
$$\int_{\mu}\frac{4z dz}{(2az+z^2+1)(2biz+z^2-1)}$$
I found the roots of the denominators, which gave me:
$$z_1^-= -a-\sqrt{a^2-1},\>\> z_1^+= -a+\sqrt{a^2-1},\>\>z_2^-= i\left(-b-\sqrt{b^2-1}\right),\>\>z_2^+= i\left(-b+\sqrt{b^2-1}\right)$$
The integral then becomes:
$$\int_{\mu}\frac{4zdz}{(z-z_1^-)(z-z_1^+)(z-z_2^-)(z-z_2^+)}$$

What is the next step? How do I simplify? I don't think partial fraction decomposition is viable, thus am kinda confused. If anyone could help me it would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: So we have two poles within the contour $\vert z\vert=1$ which are ${z_1}^+$ and ${z_2}^+$. And then use residue theorem